# print the new array of caracter ( weird symbol ) in c

Tags: c, arrays

My program prints a weird symbol after the "dc ba".  How can I avoid that?

[image]

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

void main(){

    char S[50],T[50],a;
    int i,k=0,j;

    printf("\n Donner La chaine :");
    gets(S);

    for ( i = strlen(S)-1; i>=0  ; i--)
    {
        if (S[i]==' ' && S[i-1]== ' ')
        {
            continue;
        }

        T[k]=S[i];
        k++;


    }

    puts(T);

}
```

Comment: `gets` is dangerous. use `fgets()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code

```
if (S[i]==' ' && S[i-1]== ' ')
```

will be erroneous when `i` is 0. Re-think your `for` loop logic.

Also, to use a `char` array as *string*, you need to null terminate it. use `T[k] = '\0'` outside the `for` loop.

Note: Never use `gets()` its very unsafe. Use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: thnx for the answer , but i have some question please :
1- why i will need to null terminate an array ?
2-why the gets unsafe?
3-i change the i>=0 with i>=1 and strlen(s) not streln(s)-1 and nothing appear

Comment: @Znx  1) otherwise, printf will not get to know the _end_ of the array. 2) `gets()` may create buffer overruns. 3) that's also wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1) `S[i-1]` will be undefined, when `i=0`. 
2) `T` will not be null-terminated in the end, so garbage will be printed.

Comment: i writ this new code but i still have garbage :
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main(){
 char S[50],T[50],a;
 int i,k=0,j;
 
 printf("\n Donner La chaine :");
 fgets(S,sizeof(S),stdin);
 
 for ( i = strlen(S); i>=1  ; i--)
 {
  
  if (S[i]==' ' && S[i-1]== ' ')
  {
   continue;
  }
  
  T[k]=S[i];
  k++;
  
  
 }
 
 puts(T);

}

Comment: Still no null-termination